# Using Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp class with dynamic pages based on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-apps-script, html-parsing, urlfetch

I am trying to parse a web page based on `AngularJS` with Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp class.

Elements to be retrieved appear in source code as `{{Field1}}`, `{{Field2}}` etc. After running `angular.min.js` they are replaced with their field value.

When using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` and `getContentText()`  I simply get the field name (ante `AngularJS` execution) and not the field values.

How can I get the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible with apps script.
You would need a server with a module that simulates a browser and executes the js.